# best practice to publish an ionic miniapp in an elementor html section

Tags: angular, wordpress, ionic-framework, elementor

I would like to be able to post a mini app made in ionic to calculate currencies quite complex (
It is very difficult to recreate it in php) but I would like to place or call it in an HTML section (a element) of elementor Wordpress Builder I have read that some make a plugin with a file php in wp-content/plugins (but it only works with pure angular) and I'm avoiding using IFrame, I wonder if I have to put the app root folder in a subdirectory, modify the BaseHref of angular config or if there is a way to call the index.html in the Elementor Builder html widget.

I tried to modify the basehref of the angular.config.js and the index.html or investigate how to call an html from another html but never got a solution

Comment: If this were my project, I would write a very small plugin to [define a shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/). It would display the HTML and enqueue the Javascript and CSS needed for your miniapp.  Then, just put the shortcode  on your site where you want the miniapp.

Comment: if that's exactly what i've researched, they make a shortcode to call the mini app when they do it in angular. The problem here is that when compiling for the www browser, ionic delivers many Js and css files, approximately 40 files, which are renamed in the next compilation. I wanted to know if there was a way to call all the css and js files contained in wp-admin/ miniapp

Comment: I wanted to know if this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file code worked for me without having to create a plugin or declare the 40 javascript and css that ionic compiles for me

Comment: An example of what O.Jones says is https://dev.to/stevewhitmore/take-your-wordpress-site-farther-with-angular-3o6p however my app compiled too many javascripts about 140, 2 css and 1 html so is there a way to use wp_register_script() and wp_enqueue_script() globally, so that all the JS and CSS are loaded without having to define them one by one?.